# Failed Gmail authentication through smtplib and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, smtplib

I'm trying to write an AWS Lambda function that periodically sends an email using Python's smtplib. This function works outside of AWS lambda, and I've verified that the environment variables are valid many times.

```
import os
import smtplib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Function that runs to send the email."""
    otf_email = os.environ.get("OTF_EMAIL")
    my_email = os.environ.get("MY_EMAIL")
    pw = os.environ.get("GMAIL_PW")

    body = 'Subject:\nThis is a test from the AWS lambda function.'
    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp_obj.ehlo()
    smtp_obj.starttls()
    smtp_obj.login(my_email, pw)
    smtp_obj.sendmail(my_email, otf_email, body)
    smtp_obj.sendmail(my_email, my_email, body)
    smtp_obj.quit()
```

The first part of the error:

```
"errorMessage": "(534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsR\\n5.7.14 vlSLqK014L_ddv0GicpBkQ1o229bk_zYZe8gMUGlddfJLox0EnXFwtUl9GpBygMxCzoATW\\n5.7.14 3UjdqLIvkTcUx6vGO09gE33_CMkdMaVK-F1d8FC4SypPh8n3ft6BaZubjr4b_M7FD2roiN\\n5.7.14 LyTNxCogmPGDqNQP8overGbbDNTZ7rdeEGBYqG9dExVjtqnRda6eEwC9e9Ib8zHfsjASRM\\n5.7.14 Zi8ShH9zxelYTJ-IhALwvPFV0pJIg> Please log in via your web browser and\\n5.7.14 then try again.\\n5.7.14  Learn more at\\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 u131sm4947518pgc.89 - gsmtp')"
```

Comment: I think you need to enable access to less secure apps from your gmail settings.

Comment: For your use case I recommend using Amazon SES to send email. Very easy to integrate with Lambda.

Comment: I enabled access to less secure apps in gmail. I should have said that. I'll check out SES.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides a service called [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

You can send outbound email in a scalable way.

If you still want to send email through gmail enable less secure apps option discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/8613).

Comment: I did enable less secure apps, but I'll give SES a try. Thanks!